# How to exclude a product category from query in functions.php Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the following snippet to check if an item is out of stock and if so to change its status to draft from published. How can I exlude one category in this query? Thank you!

```
add_action('admin_init', 'woo_moveoutofstocktodraft');

function woo_moveoutofstocktodraft() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    //if loggedin user does not have admin previlage
    if (!user_can($current_user, 'administrator')) {
        return;
    }
    $params = [
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ];
    $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
    if ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
            $wc_query->the_post();
            $product_id = get_the_ID();
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            //if product is Out of Stock move to draft              
  if (!$product->is_in_stock()) {
            $post = array( 'ID' => $product_id, 'post_status' => 'draft' );
            wp_update_post($post);
            }
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [tax_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) parameter in your query arg,

e.i.

```
$params = [
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'terms'     => [1,2,3,4], //ID\s of categories
            'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
        ]
    ],
];
```

But I'd say this uses way too much resources and doing a lot of useless overhead just for doing a simple thing.

your code performs the following;

1. Perform database query to read records on post table
2. Loop through each record
3. Another database query (read) for checking stock for each record on meta table (N+1 problem)
4. Then Another database query (write) for each record meeting specific condition to update a single posts table field.

you better of doing ONE raw sql UPDATE statement that joins the meta and taxonomy related table, would probably use 99% less resource than your current approach

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('admin_init', 'woo_moveoutofstocktodraft');

function woo_moveoutofstocktodraft() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    // Check if the current user is not an administrator
    if (!user_can($current_user, 'administrator')) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Define the category ID to exclude
    $excluded_category_id = 123; // Replace 123 with the ID of the category you want to exclude
    
    $params = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $excluded_category_id,
                'operator' => 'NOT IN', // Exclude products from the specified category
            ),
        ),
    );

    $wc_query = new WP_Query($params);
    if ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($wc_query->have_posts()) :
            $wc_query->the_post();
            $product_id = get_the_ID();
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            // Check if the product is out of stock and move it to draft status
            if (!$product->is_in_stock()) {
                $post = array('ID' => $product_id, 'post_status' => 'draft');
                wp_update_post($post);
            }
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
}
```

I have modified your code and in this modified code:

Replace 123 with the actual ID of the category you want to exclude.
The tax query parameter is added to the $params array to exclude products from the specified category.
The operator 'NOT IN' is used to exclude products from the specified category.